# Laravel 4 Eloquent

Tags: laravel

Recently im playing with laravel but i found something difficult.

I have 2 tables : 
**Users** table and **Images** table.

*Users table structure*

```
--users 
-id
-name 
-email , etc
```

*Images table structure*

```
--images
-id
-user_id (FK)
-avatar ( saved as path)
```

On User model i made this :

```
public function image() {

return $this->hasMany('Image');
}
```

And here is my view:

```
$users = User::all(); ( I declare this to my controller or route file)

@foreach($users as $user)
{{$user->image}}

@endforeach
```

And It shows this on  my view [ ] .

When i changed my model to this

```
  public function image(){

  return $this->hasMany('Image','user_id', 'id');
}
```

It shows all the info on images table.

**What can I do in order to output only image ? Thank you**

Comment: What do you mean "It shows all the info on images table.". Show the output.

Comment: I mean that the code outputs the id , user_id , avatar while I want avatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your view change

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$user->image}}

@endforeach
```

to

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$user->image->avatar}}

@endforeach
```

Laravel is returning a Collection object for your Image model so you just need to reference the variable you want in the loop.

Comment: Thank you , i forgot that  .

Comment: This may not work when multiple images are added  because it's a has many.  You may have to `foreach($user->image as $image)`